# How to copy Zsh aliases to Eshell

Tags: emacs, alias, zsh, eshell, emacs-prelude

I'm trying to copy using the command provided in [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias#toc9). That is,

```
alias | sed -E "s/^alias ([^=]+)='(.*)'$/alias \1 \2 \$*/g; s/'\\\''/'/g;" >~/.emacs.d/eshell/alias
```

This worked with `Bash`, I was using [Emacs-Starter-Kit](https://github.com/eschulte/emacs24-starter-kit); but not working with `Zsh` -- not working means it copied things but to no effect.

**[As a side note]**

It seems like, I don't have few `Eshell` default variables i.e. `eshell-read-aliases-list`, and `eshell-aliases-file`. So, I even don't know where should my `Eshell` alias file reside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working after setting

```
(setq eshell-directory-name (expand-file-name "./" (expand-file-name "eshell" prelude-personal-dir)))
```

in `post.el` (my personal `.el` file for post-processing) under `prelude/personal`

... and modified the given `bash` command to

```
alias | awk '{print "alias "$0}' | sed -E "s/^alias ([^=]+)='(.*)'$/alias \1 \2 \$*/g; s/'\\\''/'/g;" > ~/.emacs.d/personal/eshell/alias
```

... and appended that to `.zshrc`.

Found that `alias` command, in `zsh`, prints aliases without prefix `alias<space>`, unlike `bash`. Therefore this part

```
| awk '{print "alias "$0}'
```